# is it possible to recover the Oracle Data Pump master table?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, recover, datapump

I'm trying to import a few files with a published Oracle Data Pump perl script: [dumpinfo.pl](http://www.gokhanatil.com/2011/07/how-to-gather-the-header-information-and-the-content-of-an-export-dumpfile.html)

After successfully importing several dump files from the same export process, another file failed with:

```
# impdp system/****** DIRECTORY=RESTORE_DIR DUMPFILE=exp_%u.dmp PARALLEL=8 
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Mon Jul 7 11:40:37 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39059: dump file set is incomplete
ORA-39246: cannot locate master table within provided dump files
```

The script reports that it can't find a master table. Assuming that the master table is lost, there any mechanics for recover it?

Thanks...

Comment: Can you provide any more details about the invalid dump file?

Comment: Hi Barett, thanks for your corrections. The problem is that master table wasn't saved in the dump files, and also was erased of the databases. Therefore, there is no way to recover data with the Oracle's utilities.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-39246 cannot locate master table within provided dump files 
>   Cause:    Check the export log file and make sure all of the files that
>   were exported are included in the current job.  Action:   A Data Pump
>   IMPORT or SQL_FILE operation was being performed but not all of the
>   files from the Data Pump export dump file set were included. In
>   particular, the dump file containing the export job's master table was
>   not provided.

Check that you have all dump files in that directory and they all are accessible to impdp utility. I got this error when our backup team has restored first five dmp files, and two last ones were missing.